# Remove the border of a sf polygon when plotted with ggplot2 using geom_sf

Tags: ggplot2, border, gis, polygon, r-sf

I'm working with a shapefile converted from a raster with lots of little holes in it, therefore, the borders create big splodges in the shape when plotted.

[image]

I'm currently adding the polygon to the main plot with the below code. Despite setting the alpha value to 1 the colours are different even when both set to `"red"` which makes no sense to me.

```
geom_sf(data = filter(db, band == 9), aes(fill = "red"), colour = "red", alpha = 1)
```

Can I either:

- Set the borders to the same colour as the fill?
- Or remove the border entirely?
- Or set the border colour to none?

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that all the "stuff' inside and the thick borders on the edge are basically your x/y data that are supposed to describe the edges of the polygons, and you want to just show the shape and fill without showing the points?  If so, try setting `colour=NA` which should in theory remove the border entirely.  From your questions posed at the end... were they things you tried already?

Comment: The questions at the end were things I felt may be possible but I hadn't found a way of doing. I had tried setting colour to `"none"` but `NA` did the trick thanks :)